# Lisp format list with parameter

Tags: format, common-lisp

I'm trying to create a function that will take a string and display it.

```
(defun closing (s)
  (format t "~{~a~}" ("Sincerely," "\n" s)))
```

What I hope to get is

> Sincerely,
>
> Frank

if "Frank" is the string I passed in. It complains of the variable S is defined but never used. What am I doing wrong?

Trying to use format alone: If I declare `urname` as a defparameter to be "Frank", the following doesn't print Frank, rather just the variable name. (Without quote it complains of urname not being a function.)

```
(format t "~{~a~}" '(urname urname urname))
```

How can I feed variables to format?

Comment: See the LIST function: `(list x y z)`

Comment: @melpomene Not absolutely sure, but I don't think **list** is needed here;  `~@{` will use the remaining arguments.

Comment: @melpomene This worked, but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three issues here: (1) The code you posted doesn't just have the problem of not using **s**; it's also trying to call the *string* **"Sincerely"** as a function; (2) quoting a list means you'll get exactly what's quoted (e.g., a list of symbols, not a list of values of variables); (3) calling format with lists.

#### (something other-stuff...) is a function call

When I put the code you posted into SBCL, I get some very specific and helpful output:

```
CL-USER> (defun closing (s)
           (format t "~{~a~}" ("Sincerely," "\n" s)))
; in: DEFUN CLOSING
;     ("Sincerely," "n" S)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA CLOSING
;         (S)
;       (BLOCK CLOSING (FORMAT T "~{~a~}" ("Sincerely," "n" S))))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable S is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

**("Sincerely," "\n" s)** is an illegal function call, since a *string*, like **"Sincerely"**, can't have a function binding.  Since SBCL sees the problem in that, it recognizes that the one thing that **s** might have been used for (i.e., an argument to a function call), can't happen.  That's why you'll get the error, and then the associated style warning.

#### Creating lists of values

The second is probably answered in other questions already, but the short answer is that you want **(list x y z)**, not **'(x y z)**.  The former calls the function **list** with the *values* of the *variables* **x**, **y**, and **z**, while the latter denotes a literal list of the *symbols* **x**, **y**, and **z**.

```
CL-USER> (let ((a 42)
               (b 89))
           (print '(a b))               ; a list of two symbols
           (print (list a b)))          ; a list of two numbers
(A B) 
(42 89)
```

#### Format, iteration, &c.

The third is probably more interesting, since **format** has so many possibilities.  The ~{ and ~} in your example are used for iterating over values in a list.  First, let's look at a simple example: you can just use the format directive ~a and call format with the arguments you want to splice in:

```
CL-USER> (let ((closing "Sincerely")
               (name "Frank"))
           (format t "~a,~%~a" closing name))
Sincerely,
Frank
```

Now, if you need to print multiple values, you can use ~{ and ~} to have format iterate over a list of values:

```
CL-USER> (let ((closing "Sincerely")
               (names '("Frank" "John")))
           (format t "~a,~{~%~a~}" closing names))
Sincerely,
Frank
John
```

If the names are the values of variables, then you can either create a list containing those values:

```
CL-USER> (let ((closing "Sincerely")
               (name1 "Frank")
               (name2 "John"))
           (format t "~a,~{~%~a~}" closing (list name1 name2)))
Sincerely,
Frank
John
```

or you can change ~{ to ~@{ and have format read the *remaining* arguments as the list:

```
CL-USER> (let ((closing "Sincerely")
               (name1 "Frank")
               (name2 "John"))
           (format t "~a,~@{~%~a~}" closing name1 name2))
Sincerely,
Frank
John
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read a tutorial about format, from [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) for example

For an easy explanation

(format 
(destination-stream usually t for standard output nil to form a string) 
(here comes the string) 
(&rest variables that should write in the string where is an ~A and by position like String.format in java or c))

in your case, you need the symbol ~% or use the character for return in common lisp

```
CL-USER> (defun closing (s) (format t "~A~%~%~A" "Sincerely," s))
CLOSING
CL-USER> (closing "paco")
Sincerely,

paco
NIL
```

The nil say that the functions returns null, and the other is the standard output if you want to return a string, put nil instead of t